# Getting the sum of a column based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following first three columns of data in a select statement, I am trying to add the "total" column:

```
Customer   ReportingCategory    SumOfProfit    Total
ABC          1                     10           60
ABC          2                     25           60
ABC          4                     25           60
```

So right now, I am basically selecting Customer, ReportingCategory, and SumOfProfit and grouping by Customer, ReportingCategory, and summing SumOfProfit (this is selecting from a sub query).

I want to add the total column to look just as it does above. So it sums the entire sum of profit for the customer but still keeps the reporting categories and their individual sum of profit. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm confused... your current query works fine with the sub query correct?  You are asking what??? Are you asking if there is a better way?

Comment: Can you include the query you're using now? Ideally in a sqlfiddle...

Comment: No, I am trying to add on the "Total" column shown above. I have the first three columns. I want to add on the total column which is basically the sum of the entire sum of profit for each customer no matter what their reportingcategoryid is.

Comment: SELECT CUSTOMER, [Total] = (SELECT SUM([Profit]) FROM [Table]) FROM [Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [windowing function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.100).aspx).

```
select your_original_columns, 
sum(SumOfProfit) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer) AS 'Total'
...
```

Now, instead of SumOfProfit you likely will need your sub query, but the idea of windowing function is to return an aggregate over a different range then your group by, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can likely just add the `Total` field to your existing query using `OVER()`:

`SUM(Profit) OVER() AS Total`

If this needs to be a total per Customer or some other set of fields, you'll add `PARTITION BY`:

`SUM(Profit) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer) AS Total`

You could also use a subquery and another aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

```
select customer, ReportingCategory, SumOfProfit , sum(total)
from       (
YOUR EXISTING SELECT
)
```

This will work, If not please add your current select statement in your post.